# Does moving to Symfony 1.1/1.2 make sense?

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony1

I built an on-demand web app on Symfony 1.0. Other than brutal memory consumption, I am happy with it. Should I upgrade to 1.1/1.2? What are the main *practical* benefits *you* have enjoyed most after upgrading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main benefit lies in the new forms framework. Object layer can thus be easily linked to the data input layer, and be much more powerful and resusable. You have sets of widgets and validators, and each form can be extended like the current model layer, you can develop your own widgets and reuse them on other projects through plugins, etc..
The 1.2 is much more about the REST architecture. If you want a RESTful application, you should consider it as it implements a brand new routing framework, all object oriented.

The reason I use 1.2 is also about Doctrine full integration. Doctrine is a real jewel to play with, and definitely changes the way you build things on symfony. Couldn't go back at any price.